# TypeError at /register 'CustomUser' object is not subscriptable

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I am trying to register a new user and getting this error. I tried other similar issues and solutions but not getting headway.

**full traceback**

```py
Internal Server Error: /register
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/sharhan/DEV/PYTHON/DEVELOPMENT/allauth-tutorial/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/sharhan/DEV/PYTHON/DEVELOPMENT/allauth-tutorial/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/sharhan/DEV/PYTHON/DEVELOPMENT/allauth-tutorial/authentication/views.py", line 38, in register_view
    CustomUser.objects.get(email__iexact=email)[0]
TypeError: 'CustomUser' object is not subscriptable
```

**register_view in views.py**

```py
def register_view(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect('home')
    else:
        form = CustomUserCreationForm()
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = CustomUserCreationForm(request.POST or None)
            if form.is_valid():
                form.save()
                user_name = form.cleaned_data['username']
                messages.info(request, 'Account created for ' + user_name)
                return redirect('login')
            else:
                form = CustomUserCreationForm(request.POST)
        else:
            form = CustomUserCreationForm()
        return render(request, 'register.html', {'form': form})
```

**models.py**

```py
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    
    # add additional fields in here
    country = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    age = models.IntegerField(default=False, null=True, blank=True)
    status = models.BooleanField(default=False, null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email
```

**forms.py**

```py
class CustomUserCreationForm(UserCreationForm):  
    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        fields = ['username', 'email', 'country', 'age', 'status', 'password1', 'password2']
```

The second is that I'm also trying to implement functionality which I don't know where to start. If a new user uses the same email again to register, it should throw an error. It should be unique and no double use of email for registration. Username functionality is already implemented by Django so it throws an error if an existing username is already used

Comment: Please post the *full* traceback, [edit] the question.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Updated with full traceback

Comment: Your `register_view` has a line `ustomUser.objects.get(email__iexact=email)[0]` that appears not in the view you copied into your question...

Comment: I initially had it there but removed it actually. But the traceback keeps on telling me it is there. I've cleared my cache but it keeps telling me the error is there. What I've pasted is exactly what I'm working it.

Comment: try to remove the `*.pyc` files, and restart the Django server, likely the old code still has some bytecode variant.

Comment: I just did and It still throws the same error. I manually deleted the __pycache__ file and also use this command "find . -name "*.pyc" -exec rm -f {} \;"

Comment: are you sure the file is correctly saved? What if you open it in another editor? Are you sure it is triggering the view on line 38, and not another view that (by accident) has the same name?

Comment: You're right the vscode was not saving the file. I unchecked the auto-save and manually saved it to pick the changes. the second part as I stated in the question is that to eliminate double use of same email to register. Django already handles the username part.

Answer (score 0):

Since the first problem has been solved and was due to the IDE not saving the file not properly, this answer only addresses the second part of the question:

> The second is that I'm also trying to implement functionality which I don't know where to start. If a new user uses the same email again to register, it should throw an error.

You can make the email field unique by rewriting it in the `CustomUser` model with a [**`unique=True`** parameter [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#unique). This will enforce uniqness both for the database and for `ModelForm`s, `ModelAdmin`s, `ModelSerializer`s and a lot of other Django tooling that depends on that model:

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _

class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), unique=True)
    
    # add additional fields in here
    # ⋮

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email
```

You can then let Django construct a migration file and migrate the database. Before you can do that, you will however first have to look for duplicates in the already existing database. If that is the case, then you should resolve these first, for example by removing duplicates.

Comment: That works like charm. Thanks a lot. I actually use Django-allauth to do my authentication but this particular project needs more customization to add more user fields and roles and permissions. I really spent days trying to override django-allauth's  custom views and templates and just decided to go back and start from groundup